# Unclear error message on sending a notification to iOS

Tags: apple-push-notifications, testflight, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to send a notification via C# SDK. I'm sending notifications for iOS.

```
string payload = "{\"aps\" : { \"alert\" : \"Message received from Bob\" }}";
var outcome = hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(payload, new[] { "b6a5d9c3-4297-422f-9a8d-b7979c30a5f8" }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Registration works fine, I can retrieve registered users, but I receive errors on sending. The error message is

> Contract mismatch between ServiceBus and the Push Notification System

I've looked into manage.windowsazure.com for monitoring and saw that there were errors of type “Bad channel error”.

I assume that I should try to change my region for NH and probably the problem will go away, but is there anything else I could look at to resolve this issue?

Forgot to mention that everything was working on the first day I started to work with push notifications and only after several days became broken without any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't figured out what does that error mean but at least found the root cause. It was Testflight that by some obscure reasons uses `production` gateways to send notifications and not sandbox, and my NH has been configured with sandbox certificate, that's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you may have open port 2135 and also add APN certificate

Comment: Not sure that this suggestion is helpful. The certificate already there, created and uploaded for debug.

Comment: have u opened port  2135 in your server

Comment: Yep. Firewall is turned down.

Comment: you  should have to include that certificate file in server

Comment: this link may http://www.mattburkedev.com/ios-and-android-push-notifications-with-pushsharp/   may be helpful